# Firebase and Gitlab continuous integration pipeline failing

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am trying to hook up a simple static website to firebase hosting from Gitlab using their continuous integration tab. After downloading and installing firebase command line tools I am here:

```
  stages:
  - deploy

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - firebase use <project-name> --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
    - firebase deploy --only hosting -m "Pipe $CI_PIPELINE_ID Build $CI_BUILD_ID" --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

After that in firebase I deploy the site. However, gitlab then reports that the job is not deployed because

```
 Error: firebase use must be run from a Firebase project directory.

Run firebase init to start a project directory in the current folder.
```

I dont understand the error, as I have in fact run firebase in the project director. Or is the error referring to the image thats in the yml file?

Either way, could someone please help me out? I've found a number of blog posts using CI in gitlab with firebase but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue and solved it by check folder structure
in my case:
/root/xx_project

firebase.json is in xx_project
so I need to cd xx_project